# Overleaf, LaTeX: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: errors, subfloats, overleaf

I am writing a report. I am trying to put images side by side so I followed this [tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables#Multiple_images_in_one_figure). And I get the following errors:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % this line generates the error!!
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{images/konectom_tests/spiral.png} 
\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:subim1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{images/konectom_tests/spiral.png}
\caption{Caption 2}
\label{fig:subim2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
```

The generated error:

```
% ----> Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   }
l.408 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
                                      
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

It seems that 0.5\textwidth isn't correctly interpreted!

These are all the imports:

````
% Liste de paquets potentiellement utiles pour votre rédaction
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}      % fonctionnalités en !français (anglais)
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % support de l'encodage utf8
\usepackage{listings, listings-rust}           % permet d'insérer du code
\usepackage{hyperref}           % liens
\usepackage{subfigure}          % schémas
\usepackage{amsmath}            % pour ajouter des équations 
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}           % pour \includegraphics 
\usepackage{appendix}           % pour ajouter des appendices à votre rapport
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=2cm]{geometry} 
```
````

Comment: You need `\usepackage{subcaption}`, not ‘\usepackage{subfigure}`

Comment: It seems that the two packages conflict with each other. I removed subfigure and I no longer have the error.

Comment: Remove also the `inputenc` line , as `utf8x` is obsolete and deprecated. UTF-8 is supported out of the box.

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete package, instead it is `subfig`. However, far better is to use `subcaption`, which syntax you use in your code fragment. off-topic: `hyperref` should be loaded last in preamble ...